# Time format of posts

Tags: discussion, timestamps

Why should the Stack Overflow use such a time format?

[image]

Every time I want to see the question/answer creation time, I put the mouse on it so it show year-month-date. I think this is the most clear way to show.

Why use time format Month(show in name)+Day（show in number)+Year(also show in number)?

Comment: Well, it's the standard human-readable format in English-speaking countries. It's arguably nicer than `YYYY-MM-DD`, at least IMO

Answer (score 5):

That's the existing convention, as set by ISO 8601. Or, [alternately](http://xkcd.com/1179/):

[image]

Comment: Nice, but the question is about why not use the above instead of "Feb 27, '13".

Comment: @Arjan Ah, didn't realize that. I've CWed this since it's still relevant.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant, but it's a nice reference ;-)